# Bootstrap 3 data-toggle icon change

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this code so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/4z6j454q/

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('li').each(function() { 
      $(this).on('shown', function () {
         $(this).children().attr("src", "http://test.cz.vs1056.server4u.cz/images/right.jpg");
      });

      $(this).on('hidden', function () {
         $(this).children().attr("src", "http://test.cz.vs1056.server4u.cz/images/down.jpg");;
      });
    });
  });
```

I'm trying to display the arrow down or right depending whether the

is collapsed or not, disregarding the src in the html now.

I'm not sure why my jQuery wont work. I search for all

tags, then deciding if they are shown or hidder then editing the src of the child  tag

thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DEMO: [MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4z6j454q/3/)**

The reason your'e not getting results when clicking is because of the follwoing problems:

- there are no click events being binded to the LI. currently you are just loading the images when the page loads.
- Your'e not specifying which element is hidden or shown. By adding the `.next()` your'e telling the DOM to look to the next element in the LI list, and see if its hidden.

I would try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    function checkOnLoad(elem){
        if(elem.next().css("display") === "none"){
            elem.find('img').attr("src", "http://test.cz.vs1056.server4u.cz/images/right.jpg");
        } else {
            elem.find('img').attr("src", "http://test.cz.vs1056.server4u.cz/images/down.jpg");
        }
    }

    function checkOnClick(li_clicked){
        var id = li_clicked.attr("data-target");
         $(id).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {           
             li_clicked.children('img').attr("src", "http://test.cz.vs1056.server4u.cz/images/right.jpg");
        })

         $(id).on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
           li_clicked.children('img').attr("src", "http://test.cz.vs1056.server4u.cz/images/down.jpg");
        })
    }

    $('li').each(function() { 
        checkOnLoad($(this));
    });

    $('li').click(function() { 
        checkOnClick($(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: Almost there, this makes all images to display correctly on load. However on the first click nothing happens. The second click on the element triggers the change, but it's not the right image (due to the fact that the first click was skipped). Any solutions to this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure why, but this does not work properly. The first one was the closest.

Comment: Ok this should work. You need two different functions.

Comment: @selez your'e welcome. I hope you were able to get it working. Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for bootstrap's `shown.bs.collapse` and `hidden.bs.collapse` events rather than just 'shown' and 'hidden'.

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('li').each(function() {
        var li = $(this);
        li.on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
           li.children().attr("src", "http://test.cz.vs1056.server4u.cz/images/right.jpg");
        });

        li.on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
           li.children().attr("src", "http://test.cz.vs1056.server4u.cz/images/down.jpg");;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for submitting, this does not trigger any change however. :/

Answer (score 0):

This works, not sure why though.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    function checkCollapsed(elem){
      if(elem.next().css("display") === "none"){
           elem.children().attr("src", "http://test.cz.vs1056.server4u.cz/images/right.jpg");;
      } else {
           elem.children().attr("src", "http://test.cz.vs1056.server4u.cz/images/down.jpg");
      }
    }

    function checkCollapsed2(elem){
      if(elem.next().css("display") === "none"){
           elem.children().attr("src", "http://test.cz.vs1056.server4u.cz/images/down.jpg");;
      } else {
           elem.children().attr("src", "http://test.cz.vs1056.server4u.cz/images/right.jpg");
      }
    }

    $('li').each(function() { 
          checkCollapsed($(this));
    });

    $('li').click(function() { 
           checkCollapsed2($(this));
    });
});
```